# Can anyone let me know why am I getting this error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, watchify

I am just starting to learn `ReactJS` with `NodeJS` and trying to run an application through `NPM` but just right on start I am getting the following error as :

```
You MUST specify an outfile with -o.
```

My Starting Command :

```
watchify src/main.jsx -v -t [ babelify --presets [ react ]] -o public/js/main.js
```

Whole Error :

```
C:\Users\Umair Shah Yousafzai\react-skeleton>npm start

> react-skeleton@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Umair Shah Yousafzai\react-skeleton 
> watchify src/main.jsx -v -t [ babelify --presets [ react ]] -o public/js/main.js

You MUST specify an outfile with -o.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm v3.8.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! react-skeleton@1.0.0 start: watchify src/main.jsx -v -t [ babelify --presets [ react ]] -o public/js/main.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-skeleton@1.0.0 start script 'watchify src/main.jsx -v -t [ babelify --presets [ react ]] -o public/js/main.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the react-skeleton package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! watchify src/main.jsx -v -t [ babelify --presets [ react ]] -o public/js/main.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs react-skeleton
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls react-skeleton
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Umair Shah Yousafzai\react-skeleton\npm-debug.log
```

**MY EFFORT TO SOLVE IT :**

I have tried removing `node_modules` folder and then running back `npm install` but still I am getting the same error And my `NPM` Version is 3.8.9

**My Files :**

**`main.jsx`** :

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var List = require('./components/List.jsx');

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('ingredients'));
```

**`List.jsx`** :

```
var React = require('react');
var Listitem = require('./Listitem.jsx');

var ingredients = [{"id":1,"text":"ham"},{"id":2,"text":"cheese"},{"id":3,"text":"potatos"}];

var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var listItems = ingredients.map(function(item) {
            return <Listitem key={item.id} ingredient={item.text} />
        });
        return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>);
    }

});

module.exports = List;
```

**`Listitem.jsx`** :

```
var React = require('react');
var Listitem = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
          return (
            <li>
                <h4>{this.props.ingredient}</h4>
            </li>
          );
     }

});

module.exports = ListItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put -o {src} as the very first option; the -t option's subargument syntax may mess here.

```
watchify src/main.jsx -o public/js/main.js -v -t [ babelify --presets [ react ]]
```

Also, you need to fix your jsx files.

main.jsx:

```
ReactDOM.render("<List />", document.getElementById('ingredients'));
```

List.jsx :

```
return "<Listitem key={item.id} ingredient={item.text} />"

return "<ul>{listItems}</ul>";
```

Listitem.jsx :

```
return "<li><h4>{this.props.ingredient}</h4></li>";
```

Comment: By adding your code I am getting now the following error : `Error: Parsing file C:\Users\Umair Shah Yousafzai\react-skeleton\src\main.jsx: Unexpected token (5:16)`

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai well, that's another (unrelated) error - you probably need to fix your jsx file. But I guess the original issue is now fixed.

Comment: I am updating my question with `main.jsx` file..!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai the line:

    ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('ingredients'));

must be

ReactDOM.render("<List />", document.getElementById('ingredients'));

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai (enclose the <List /> in quotes)

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai same with the Listitem.jsx: enclose all the DOM-related parts into quotes.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai and List.jsx (must be return ("<ul>{listItems}</ul>"); etc).

Comment: Can you please let me know that why am I getting the following error as : `main.js:820 Uncaught Invariant Violation: ReactCompositeComponent.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: Also here is the code due to which I am getting this error as : `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(List,null), document.getElementById('ingredients'));`

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai please create a plunkr and post it in another question; it's no good for StackOverflow to have lengthy troubleshooting in comments.