# Getting Uncaught Invariant Violation: ReactCompositeComponent.render(): error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just started learning `ReactJS` and on running my app for first time I am getting the following error as :

> main.js:820 Uncaught Invariant Violation:
>   ReactCompositeComponent.render(): A valid React element (or null) must
>   be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other
>   invalid object.

I have hosted my project at Github as the `main.js` file is too large to add in here so that's why here is the link to the `main.js` as :

https://github.com/nicefellow1234/react-skeleton/blob/master/public/js/main.js

The Error started when I modified this line as :

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(List,null), document.getElementById('ingredients'));
```

This Question of mine is related to this one older question :

[Can anyone let me know why am I getting this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610092/can-anyone-let-me-know-why-am-i-getting-this-error)

Comment: What is List inside React.createElement(List,null)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always returning a String instead of an Element in your render methods.

You got

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var listItems = ingredients.map(function(item) {
            return "<Listitem key={item.id} ingredient={item.text} />"; // This is wrong
        });
        return "<ul>{listItems}</ul>"; // This is wrong
    }

});


var ListItem = React.createClass({
     render: function() {
         return ("<li><h4>{this.props.ingredient}</h4></li>"); // This is wrong
     }

});
```

and it should be

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var listItems = ingredients.map(function(item) {
            return <ListItem key={item.id} ingredient={item.text} />;
        });
        return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
    }

});


var ListItem = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
          return (<li><h4>{this.props.ingredient}</h4></li>);
     }

});
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44379/)

PD: Next time you should add your components instead of your bundle file in the question, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes besides I was getting parsing error when I didn't enquoted the `ReactDOM` elements on using the following command as : `watchify src/main.jsx -o public/js/main.js -v -t [ babelify --presets [ react ]]`

Comment: For instance as this one : `Error: Parsing file C:\Users\Umair Shah Yousafzai\react-skeleton\src\components\List.jsx: Unexpected token (9:19)`

Answer (score 0):

I did not read the whole js file as it is very big but this error comes when you do not **return** in **render** method. 
Make sure you are using **return** statement in every render method.